# Remove rows in R that are before a set date, but the set date differs depending on the subject

Tags: r

Here is the reproducible data:

```
library(tidyverse)
Subject <- c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5), rep(3,5), rep(4,5), rep(5,5))
StartDate <- rep(c("2020-09-01", "2020-09-02", "2020-09-03", "2020-09-04", "2020-09-05"),5)
Test <- c("N","Y","N","N","N",
          "N","N","Y","N","N", 
          "Y","N","N","N","N",
          "N","N","N","Y","N",
          "N","N","N","N","Y")
data_test <- tibble(Subject, StartDate, Test) %>% arrange(Subject)
```

My goal is to filter out rows of data that have `StartDate` values ON and BEFORE the day of each subject's test. The thing is - each subject received their test on different days, so I can't just put a singular date in `filter()`.

That means:

For Subject 1, I'd keep their data from `"2020-09-03"`, `"2020-09-04"`, and `"2020-09-05"`

For Subject 2, I'd keep their data from `"2020-09-04"` and `"2020-09-05"`

For Subject 3, I'd keep their data from `"2020-09-02"`, `"2020-09-03"`,`"2020-09-04"`, and `"2020-09-05"`

etc.

What's the best way to proceed?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that sometimes, each subject will undergo multiple tests. I only want to keep data after their most recent test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data is ordered by `StartDate` within `Subject` you could do:

```
data_test %>% 
   group_by(Subject) %>%
   filter(cumsum(Test == "Y") > 0 & Test != "Y")
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#> # Groups:   Subject [4]
#>    Subject StartDate  Test 
#>      <dbl> <chr>      <chr>
#>  1       1 2020-09-03 N    
#>  2       1 2020-09-04 N    
#>  3       1 2020-09-05 N    
#>  4       2 2020-09-04 N    
#>  5       2 2020-09-05 N    
#>  6       3 2020-09-02 N    
#>  7       3 2020-09-03 N    
#>  8       3 2020-09-04 N    
#>  9       3 2020-09-05 N    
#> 10       4 2020-09-05 N
```

Comment: To drop the days with the test, add another filter to the end `%>% filter(Test == "N")`

Answer (score 3):

This can be easily done by grouping

```
library(tidyverse)
Subject <- c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5), rep(3,5), rep(4,5), rep(5,5))
StartDate <- rep(c("2020-09-01", "2020-09-02", "2020-09-03", "2020-09-04", "2020-09-05"),5)
Test <- c("N","Y","N","N","N",
          "N","N","Y","N","N", 
          "Y","N","N","N","N",
          "N","N","N","Y","N",
          "N","N","N","N","Y")
data_test <- tibble(Subject, StartDate, Test) %>% arrange(Subject)

data_test %>% 
  group_by(Subject) %>% 
  filter(StartDate > StartDate[Test == "Y"]) %>% 
  ungroup()


# A tibble: 10 x 3
   Subject StartDate  Test 
     <dbl> <chr>      <chr>
 1       1 2020-09-03 N    
 2       1 2020-09-04 N    
 3       1 2020-09-05 N    
 4       2 2020-09-04 N    
 5       2 2020-09-05 N    
 6       3 2020-09-02 N    
 7       3 2020-09-03 N    
 8       3 2020-09-04 N    
 9       3 2020-09-05 N    
10       4 2020-09-05 N
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data_test)[data_test[, .I[cumsum(Test == 'Y') > 0 &
       Test != 'Y'], Subject]$V1]
```

-output

```
#     Subject  StartDate Test
# 1:       1 2020-09-03    N
# 2:       1 2020-09-04    N
# 3:       1 2020-09-05    N
# 4:       2 2020-09-04    N
# 5:       2 2020-09-05    N
# 6:       3 2020-09-02    N
# 7:       3 2020-09-03    N
# 8:       3 2020-09-04    N
# 9:       3 2020-09-05    N
#10:       4 2020-09-05    N
```